# configuring iodbc to use FreeTDS for MS SQL Server under cygwin

Tags: sql-server, cygwin, odbc, freetds, iodbc

I'm trying to use RODBC to make a connection to a SQL Server database from R under cygwin.

I've installed `libiobbc` and `libiodbc-devel`, which I understand provide the driver manager that the RODBC package needs.

I installed `freetds`, which I understand provides an ODBC driver that can connect to a MS SQL server database. I used its `tsql` command-line tool to confirm that I can make a connection to a SQL Server.

I now understand the task to be pointing the driver manager (iODBC) to the driver (freeTDS), so that I can make a connection to the SQL Server database from R's `RODBC` library

The [User Guide to freeTDS](http://freetds.schemamania.org/userguide/dsnless.htm) hints that the driver that freeTDS provides should be at `/usr/local/freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so`, and that something like the following should define this driver to idobc:

```
;
; odbcinst.ini
;
[FreeTDS]
Driver = /usr/local/freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

But I don't have `libtdsodbc.so` on my system, and it appears that the cygwin package `freetds` does not provide it ([listing of installed binaries and support files](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Ffreetds%2Ffreetds-0.91-4&grep=freetds))

How can I configure idobc to use the freeTDS driver to connect to MS SQL?

**EDIT**

A colleague located `/lib/cygtdsodbc.dll` and `/usr/lib/cygtdsodbc.dll` on my system. Might this be the cygwin equivalent of `libtdsodbc.so`?

I created an `odbcinst.ini` file with the following content to define the driver:

```
[ODBC Drivers]
FreeTDS = Installed

[FreeTDS]
Driver = /usr/lib/cygtdsodbc.dll
```

and an `odbc.ini` file defining a data source `my_db`, using the driver defined above:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
my_db = FreeTDS

[my_db]
Driver = /usr/lib/cygtdsodbc.dll
Database = db_name
Host = server_dns_name
Port = 1433
```

running `iodbctest` to check things out gives

```
$ iodbctest
iODBC Demonstration program
This program shows an interactive SQL processor
Driver Manager: 03.52.0812.0326

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list): ?

DSN                              | Driver
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
my_db                            | FreeTDS

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list): my_db
1: SQLDriverConnect = [iODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocEnv() failed (0) SQLSTATE=IM004
1: ODBC_Connect = [iODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocEnv() failed (0) SQLSTATE=IM004
```

Comment: `/usr/lib/cygtdsodbc.dll` is the equivalent of `libtdsodbc.so` (and `/usr/lib` == `/lib` on Cygwin).  This looks like a configuration issue; see [chapter 4 of the FreeTDS User Guide](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/prepodbc.htm) for tips.

Answer (score 0):

The `iodbctest` program indicates it can't find **my_db**; that's your clue that it's not configured correctly.

Have another look at the FreeTDS User Guide, specifically at what properties can and can't be in `odbc.ini`.  You need a *server* or *servername* property in your `odbc.ini`, depending on whether or not you want to use your `freetds.conf` file to identify the server.